# Compose crash with use Samsung's S Pen

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, samsung-galaxy

Hold S Pen's button, then touch the screen, app crash.
log in here:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Compose assumes that all pointer ids in MotionEvents are first provided alongside ACTION_DOWN or ACTION_POINTER_DOWN.  This appears not to have been the case

Comment: You were right to reports it to [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196857015), I doubt there's anything you can do until official support

Comment: This is the way

Comment: Does this happen with any Compose app?

Comment: Yep. It happen with JetNews, a Google's Compose sample, link:https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/JetNews